# What does the reset button on a modem do?

Tags: modem, reset

I've been having trouble with my Zyxel VDSL modem not saving settings, so I figured if I reset it, then it might clear the memory. But these existing settings are still there afterward.

So what exactly does the reset button do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can often depend on how long you hold the button down. Usually pressing it once will reset your connection settings. This can be useful if, for example, you are having issues connecting to your admin page via a web browser.

Should you wish to restore everything to factory default (usually) you can hold the button down for 30 seconds. You can check with your manufacturer should you have any problems with this.

Comment: The issue I had was not holding it down long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Well usually it restores the factory default settings. Sometimes you need to hold it down for a good 30 seconds. Also check the manufacturers website for a firmware upgrade.